# Read 2 files, add something in between each line

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
    eeee = input('\nWhat do you want to combine each other with? ')
    first = []
    second = []
    with open('First.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            first.append(line)
    with open('Second.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            second.append(line)
    with open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as f:
        for thing in first:
            for thing2 in second:
                f.write(thing + str(eeee) + thing2)
```

I want to get first line from file1, add something in the middle of it (whatever eeee is inputted as) and then print the first line from file2 and then get second line and repeat

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: @Prune I know the code is quite weird but that's the best I could do

Comment: You've entirely dodged the point of my comment.  Please read the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, using [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) and [openning multiple files](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-open-multiple-files-using-with-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20open()%20to%20open,files%20at%20the%20same%20time.):

```
eeee = input('\nWhat do you want to combine each other with? ')


with open('First.txt', 'r') as f1, open('Second.txt', 'r') as f2,open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as fnew:
    for first, second in zip(f1.readlines(),f2.readlines())
            fnew.write(first.replace('\n','')+' '+ str(eeee)+' '+ second)
```

Comment: It works although it does a new line, then adds it and then a new line and adds 'second'

Comment: I want the output to be:
first = 'hi'
second = 'bye'
eeee = ' and '
fnew.write(first + eeee + second)
which would output 'hi and bye'
this is an example

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot it, that happens because each first is a line and has '\n' breakline character see my edit, you avoid that replacing '\n'.

Comment: this is what happens https://gyazo.com/6044b1059f2e425690808d4213ea4164

Comment: That happens in spite of adding first.replace('\n','')?

Comment: ```
with open('First.txt', 'r') as f1, open('Second.txt', 'r') as f2,open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as fnew:
    for first, second in zip(f1.readlines(),f2.readlines())
            fnew.write(first.replace('\n','')+' '+ str(eeee)+' '+ second)
```
this works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want `str(eeee)` for all strings in `second`, you could just add it to the starting of all items of that list.

```py
third = [str(eeee)+i for i in second]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, just change this part:

```
with open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as f:
    for thing in first:
        for thing2 in second:
            f.write(thing + str(eeee) + thing2)
```

to:

```
with open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as f:
    for thing,thing2 in zip(first,second):
        f.write(thing + str(eeee) + thing2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not combining mutiple lines of First.txt together, nor multiple lines of Second.txt with each other, I wouldn't use *any* solution involving `readlines()` as there's no reason to read either file completely into memory.

The most you need to read at any time is one line of each file.  I'd suggest a solution along lines of:

```
eeee = input('\nWhat do you want to combine each other with? ')

with open('First.txt') as left, open('Second.txt') as right:
    with open('NewStuff.txt', 'a') as output:

        for line in left:
                output.write(line.rstrip('\n') + eeee + right.readline())
```

And avoid any solution that preserves your calls to `readlines()` or introduces new ones.  Note that we `rstrip('\n')` the end of the left line so that we end up with a single output line.  Now you need to consider what happens if the two input files do not contain the same number of lines.